# Converting multiple files from .doc to .pdf

Tags: c#

I have multiple word files (more than 1500), and I want to convert them to PDF programmatically. I use the following function

```
public static void convertor(string filename)
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    File.SetAttributes(filename, FileAttributes.Temporary);
    wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(filename);
    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(filename.ToString() + ".pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

}
```

but I get the following dialog for each file

[image]

How can I unlock the files programmatically?

Comment: interop is yucky for releasing stuff properly.  Related to excel interop, but might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change your method call to `Open` to pass along a read-only flag.

```
appWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=filename, ReadOnly:=True);
```

Read more over at [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx).  You probably want to only open one instance of Word -- and explicitly close each file when you're done -- because with the number of files you're processing, you'll run out of RAM quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I moved all the files from system partition to removable flash memory and it's worked.